# How to programmatically add a UILabel with variable height and layout ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uilabel, autolayout

I have been searching for the whole day, but could not make it work.

I have a `UIView` with two labels, on above the other, on the left side, and one button on the right side. I added the constraints to let `autolayout` resize views accordingly. Everything was working perfectly when I had set one constraint for the height of the `UIView` (and no one constraint for the height of the two `UILabel`), but as the content of the lower `UILabel` will vary, I removed that constraint and set two constraints for the `UILabel`, one fixed for the upper `UILabel` and one with relation "greater than or equal" for the lower `UILabel`, and other one to fix the distance between the lower `UILabel` and the `UIView`.

It looks like auto layout is not capable of calculate the `intrinsicContentSize` of the lower `UILabel`, because it never increases its height above 10px, despite the content of the lower `UILabel`.

```
UIView *miView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *miLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[miLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[miDetailsLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
[miDetailsLabel setText:@"Just one line."];
[miView addSubview:miLabel];
UILabel *miDetailsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[miDetailsLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[miDetailsLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[miDetailsLabel setText:@"Enough text to show 3 lines on an IP4, except first of three UILabels on my test code, with no content"];
[miView addSubview:miDetailsLabel];
UIButton *miButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[miButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[miView addSubview:miButton];

NSArray *constraint_inner_h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[label]-(10)-[button(52)]-(0)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel, @"button":miButton}];
NSArray *constraint_inner2_h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[details]-(10)-[button]-(0)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"details":miDetailsLabel, @"button":miButton}];
NSArray *constraint_label_v = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(0)-[label(18)]-(2)-[details(>=10)]-(0)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel, @"details":miDetailsLabel}];
NSArray *constraint_button_v = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button(22)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"button":miButton}];
[miView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:miButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:miView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[miView addConstraints:constraint_inner_h];
[miView addConstraints:constraint_inner2_h];
[miView addConstraints:constraint_label_v];
[miView addConstraints:constraint_button_v];
```

I ve put a reduced version of the code.

any ideas of what I am missing?

Thanks

UPDATE : Thanks to Matt advice, I've tried this solution to set the proper value to `preferredMawLayoutWidth:`

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSArray *allKeys = [dictOpcionesTickets allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in allKeys) {
        NSArray *tmpArray = [dictOpcionesTickets objectForKey:key];
        if (![[tmpArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@""]) {
            UILabel *tmpLabel = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:3];
            tmpLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tmpLabel.frame.size.width;
            NSLog(@"width: %f",tmpLabel.frame.size.width);
        }
    }
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

To explain the code, as I said, I'm doing it dynamically, so I've created a dictionary with an array with the references to my `UILabel` (among other interesting information). When I run the code, I get the next log (with the code parsing 3 `UILabel`, first label with no content):

```
2014-12-28 20:40:42.898 myapp[5419:60b] width: 0.000000
2014-12-28 20:40:42.912 myapp[5419:60b] width: 0.000000
2014-12-28 20:40:43.078 myapp[5419:60b] width: 229.000000
2014-12-28 20:40:43.080 myapp[5419:60b] width: 229.000000
2014-12-28 20:40:43.326 myapp[5419:60b] width: 229.000000
2014-12-28 20:40:43.327 myapp[5419:60b] width: 229.000000
```

But I'm still getting the same result...the UIView is still showing a height equals to the minimum height set by the constraints, not showing the content of the `UILabel`.

UPDATE 2 Still fooling around.

I've tested my initial code but simplified on a fresh project in xcode 6, running on an actual iPhone 4 with iOS7, and it worked perfectly without setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` or subclassing `UILabel`, and even without calling `layoutIfNeeded` on parent view. But when it comes to the real project (I think it was originally builded in xcode 4 or 5) it does not work:

```
- (void)addLabelsDinamically {
    self.labelFixed.text = @"Below this IB label goes others added dinamically...";

    UIButton *miBoton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    miBoton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [miBoton setTitle:@"Hola" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.viewLabels addSubview:miBoton];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:miBoton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.viewLabels attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[boton(22)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"boton":miBoton}]];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[boton(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"boton":miBoton}]];

    UILabel *miLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    miLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    miLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    miLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    miLabel.text = @"ñkhnaermgñlkafmbñlkadnlñejtnhalrmvlkamnñnañorenoetñnngñsdbmnñgwn";
    [self.viewLabels addSubview:miLabel];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(8)-[label]-(10)-[boton]-(8)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"boton":miBoton}]];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previous]-(8)-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"previous":self.labelFixed}]];
    UIView *pre = miLabel;

    miLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    miLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    miLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    miLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    miLabel.text = @"ñkhnaermgñlkafmbñlkadnlñejtnhalrmvlkamnñnañorenoetñnngñsdbmnñgwn";
    [self.viewLabels addSubview:miLabel];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(8)-[label]-(10)-[boton]-(8)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"boton":miBoton}]];
    [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previous]-(8)-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"previous":pre}]];
}
```

Ah, on the same screen I have one `UILabel` added on IB, with `numberOfLines` set to '0', vertical constraint "greater or equal than" and horizontal constraint set in a similar way (but both constraints set on IB)...and it works perfectly...this is driving me nuts!! any help???

Comment: I have not tried out your code, but before we get more deeply involved in this, please try setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of both labels to their actual width and see if that helps. That is the setting that tells a label how to grow vertically.

Comment: Ok, I ve seen that property on my research, but not used it because my labels width also depends on  the superview's width. What should I put on "preferredMaxLayoutWidth"?

Comment: Well, before we get into that, even, let's start with some code that actually works. The code you have given is completely pointless because you have not assigned any `numberOfLines` value to your labels. Without that, they won't wrap at all in any case. So, let me give you a chance to revise your code code until it actually has something to wrap / grow and then we can talk more. And please also give your labels some text so we can see whether anything is really happening.

Comment: Matt, first thaks for your time, in my actual code I have set both "numberOfLines" and some text to them, just didn't put it on the example code (sorry for that).
Thanks to your advice about "preferredMaxLayoutWidth" I've found something I'm trying right now: [link](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html)

Comment: I forgot, numberOfLines = 0.

Comment: Does miView have a width constraint? Without one, your details label can expand horizontally forever, giving it no need to expand vertically.

Comment: But numberOfLines is _not_ 0. I'm not willing to make up code for you; you need to supply code that I can test as is. If you're not interested, fine, you're not interested.

Comment: Yes rdelmar, it has constraints working properly.
Matt, I've corrected it in the code posted. Now I see I didn't put the final line, adding "miView" to view on a scroll view (all this is working fine), expanding and scrolling perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, finally I've found the error, as I stated in the "UPDATE 2", it was very strange that it was working on an `UILabel` added via IB, but not with those added dynamically.

So, I looked again to my screen on IB, and found that I have an height constraint with "equal" relation, when I changed it to "greater or equal than" it all started to work!!!! Why I did not notice that the constraint was not "greater or equal than"? Because the view with the constraint was getting larger and larger as I was adding views with labels inside. Is that a bug?

Well, to summarize if someone find this useful. **"How to add `UILabel`s multi-line which adapts to its content?"**

In *iOS 6 versions* it was a bug with "`preferredMaxLayoutWidth`", not getting the width once it was "layouted", and as a result of that programmers must set it via code (the best solution is doing it dynamically, an example of that I put it on my above question).

Fortunately on *iOS7 and later*, this has been solved, and you can rely only with constraints.

1. Adding via IB

   - Add the `UILabel`, and set "number of lines" to '0' (this will make the `UILabel` use as many lines as it needs).
   - Add the constraints, you need at least 3 constraints (pin to top or bottom, and both sides), the fourth will be height with a relation "greater or equal than".
   - Be sure than the view container has enough room, or also has a height constraint with a relation "greater or equal than".
2. Adding via code (just paste the code posted above):

   ```
   UILabel *miLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; // Initialitze the UILabel
   miLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  // Mandatory to disable old way of positioning
   miLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   miLabel.numberOfLines = 0;  // Mandatory to allow multiline behaviour
   miLabel.text = @"ñkhnaergñsdbmnñgwn"; // big test to test
   [self.viewLabels addSubview:miLabel];  // Add subview to the parent view
   [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[label]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel}]];  // horizontal constraint
   [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel}]];
   UIView *pre = miLabel;

   // Adding a second label to test the separation
   miLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   miLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   miLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   miLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   miLabel.text = @"ñkhnaermgñlkafmbnoetñnngñsdbmnñgwn";
   [self.viewLabels addSubview:miLabel];
   [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[label]-(10)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"boton":miBoton}]];
   [self.viewLabels addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previous]-(10)-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":miLabel,@"previous":pre}]];
   ```

Thanks to those who has tried to help me!! This site is amazing :)

Comment: `miLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` saved me. My constraints would not work if this is not set.

Comment: Of course this will work as you are giving the text information before you add the constraints. But if you add the text after then your need a different method.

Answer (score -1):

This answer will work in a programmatic situation when you are added the text information dynamically and if this above is on a `UICollectionViewCell` or `UITableViewCell`.

In these situations you will need to update the layout and constraints on the `contentView`, then set the preferedWidth:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{

[super layoutSubviews];

[self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

//locationName.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = locationName.frame.size.width;
//locationDetails.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = locationDetails.frame.size.width;

[super layoutSubviews];
}
```

This is similar to other answers where u are getting the new frame information and using that for the preferredMaxLayoutWidth then updating the view.

You will need constraints added to those views for the vertical as a start point and the `UILabel` need their `numberOfLines = 0`

On second thoughts setting he `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in the layoutSubViews is poor solution if your width changes, as well as the height. Best to set this else where like the init for that cell. In some ways it might not be needed if you are constraining the width. This in my situation lead to the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` changing each time that cell was set.